# why is the dropdown value always null in database mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I am creating a registration form, there is a field called gender in drop down list. when I select Male or Female from the gender drop down list the value will always be null and return a validation message "Male or Female is not valid for the field"

controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "ID, FirstName,DOB,Gender")] AgentMaster agentMaster)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(agentMaster.Gender)))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Gender", "Gender is required");
        }


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.AgentMasters.Add(agentMaster);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(agentMaster);
    }
```

view

```
@model A.Models.AgentMaster

 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Gender, new SelectList(new[] { "Male", "Female" }),"--select--")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

in model gender is given as

```
public Nullable<short> Gender { get; set; }
```

when I debug the code using break points the vale for gender in [httppost] is null, but by giving 1 or 0 it works. so I use validation in controller to convert to string, but it is not working. Iam not getting where I need to change. can anyone please help to find solution ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your generating a `<select>` which posts back a `string` (either `"Male"` or `"Female"` which cannot be bound to a `short`.

Change the property to `string`, or if you do want `short` then you need to generate an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` that has the corresponding `Value`, for example

```
new List<SelectListItem>()
{
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "0", Text = "Male" },
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "Female" }
};
```

however, storing a `Gender` as a numeric value makes no sense, and the property should be a string or an enum.

Comment: I have got this as correct but the value is not showing in the details , delete and index page ??

Comment: I have no idea what your code in those methods are (and I don't even know which of the above options you chose) I assume you chose the correct one which is a string so not sure what your problem is.

Comment: I have written by using text and value, the value 0 or 1 is entering to the database but is showing in the index page (index action method)

Comment: Showing what in the index page? - if you really have kept it as 0 and 1, then of course it will shown in the Index page a 0 and 1! What are you expecting?

Comment: gender value is blank in the index page but it is showing in the database. the data is not retrieving from table

Comment: I'm not psychic and can't guess what your code is. Ask a new question with the relevant code.

Comment: return View(await db.AgentMasters.ToListAsync());

Comment: Ask a new question with all the relevant code. I have already answered this one.